# Como direccionar al "Explorador de Archivos" con un boton en HTML

Tags: html

Estoy tratando de abrir el explorador de archivos de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con un boton en HTMl, pero no lo encontre.
no necesariamente me tiene que traer un documento, sino que quiero que se habra como si estuviera abriendo una pagina, para visualizar.

se podra realizar?

Comment: Estas trabajando con electron?

Comment: no naa, solo uso el editor sublime text y  xampp

Comment: No comprendo porque entonces si no estas creando una aplicación de escritorio, quieres manipular el entorno de windows y a de mas con javascript... No es posible esto, ya que JavaScript es un lenguaje de programación para navegadores y algunos entornos o frameworks específicos. Te recomiendo que definas bien que quieres hacer y cuales herramientas son las adecuadas para su fin, un saludo Kevin.

Comment: Como opción, puedes poner la ruta de la carpeta que quieres en el navegador y tu navegador mostrara lo que hay dentro de esa ruta especifica.

Comment: Según [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder) pregunta, no es posible sin algunas configuraciones del navegador, y aún así parece que solo se puede en Firefox. Nota que la pregunta es de 2009 y puede que Mozilla haya retirado esa función de Firefox

Comment: ayaaa, pense que si era posible

Answer (score 0):

Pues para abrir un explorador de archivos en html solo basta con esta etiqueta `<input type="file">`

Comment: claro, pero eso  cuando necesariamente busco un documento, pero lo que yo quiero es solo visualizar el explorador de archivos